# SharePoint Online Web Part From Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, folder, library

I have a SharePoint online instance, with wiki pages that hold information regarding content. What I need is to easily add web parts to those pages that show documents in a **specific folder** in a document library on the same SharePoint. Is this possible?

I've tried several things to no avail. Some links have suggested using a page viewer web part set to folder, but that doesn't seem to work for me (using the syntax "file://https:\company.sharepoint.com\Library\Folder". What am I doing wrong? I can set it as a web page not folder, but then I get duplicates of the left toolbar etc and I really just want to show the folder contents.

Please somebody must have done this before? It hardly seems like an edge case and it astonishes me that you can't just do it with an app part for the library.

I've even edited the CAML query to add the FileDirRef but I'm then getting no files in the folder.

Comment: Stop using folders, use metadata instead.  Create a web page, put the web part there, and add a list view web part that is filtered to show the documents you want displayed.

Comment: Believe me, I want to use metadata. But the users in my organisation want to use folders because that's what they know.

Comment: I think, for the CAML query to work, you have to set the scope of the `<View>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was this:

1. Set the web part's View `Scope="RecursiveAll"`
2. Set the view's query to contain `<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileDirRef"/><Value Type="Text">/subsite/library/Folder Name</Value></Eq></Where>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a content query webpart to the page. Then edit the properties select the list you want to display.

Then set the filter property URL path to target your specific folder.

Comment: This is a good start, but it doesn't behave like a library web part. For example, the first item is the folder itself, and the list doesn't show column information. Any way to style it?